# i can't understand this error in ecplise why can't connect to my database?

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger  (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
 log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [spring_hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getConnectionProvider()Lorg/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/ConnectionProvider;
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.App.main(App.java:17)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getConnectionProvider()Lorg/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/ConnectionProvider;
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.getDataSource(SessionFactoryUtils.java:90)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateTransactionManager.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
... 12 more
```

my configuration file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">



       <context:component-scan base-package="java.com" />
       <context:annotation-config />

      <!--    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/> -->
       <bean id="transactionManager"  
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">  
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />  
       </bean> 

      <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/webservices" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="1234" />
</bean>



            <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="java.com" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

in this project i use maven spring and hibernate the IDE is eclipse
i try to register data in my data base but i have the error , so please help me to resolve this problem. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would guess you added Hibernate 3.x jars, but you need Hibernate 4.x jars when using

`org.springframework.orm.` **`hibernate4`** `.HibernateTransactionManager`

---

`org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getConnectionProvider()` exists in `hibernate-core-4.1.7.jar` but it is marked `@Deprecated`. If you use a newer Version (hibernate >= 4.2) then check if this method exits, if not I would recommend to downgrade hibernate library to 4.1.x.

Comment: thank y but i i resolve this error by your help and i have also  a new error Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'a' is defined

Comment: Monsier Jab: first try to fix it by your self, google for it... If you can not fix it, then read Stackoverflow "how to ask" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, and then post a new question.

Comment: Interestingly, I'm seeing this error with hibernate 4.3.1, but as far as I can see from examining the jar this method does still exist.

Comment: Ah, hold on, the return type has changed from org/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/ConnectionProvider to org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/connections/spi/ConnectionProvider.  That would explain the discrepancy.